# Why is my dynamic pie chart showing incorrect values?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a list of integers between 0 and 100 - to signify percentages. I calculate another list that is the items in the first list subtracted from 100.  I feed these to a callback so I can see the pie chart change.

The pie chart is to show positive reactions versus negative reactions by a group of survey takers

```
    pie_positive = line3_coords[n]
    pie_negative = 100 - (line3_coords[n])

line3_coords [80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 86, 86, 87, 87, 88, 88, 88, 89, 89, 90, 90, 90, 91, 91, 92, 92, 93, 93, 93, 94, 94, 95, 95, 96, 96, 96, 97, 97, 98, 98, 99, 96, 94, 92, 90, 88, 85, 83, 81, 79, 77, 74, 72, 70, 68, 66, 63, 61, 59, 57, 55, 52, 50, 48, 46, 44, 41, 39, 37, 35, 33, 30, 28, 26, 24, 22, 19, 17, 15, 13, 11, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20]
```

When pie_positive is greater or they are equal - works fine the positive slice follows line3_coords[n] values which shows as a green slice in my pie chart - the negative shows as a red slice.

when pie_negative is greater the colours flip - the labels and values are still correct but the red slice now shows the negative values and green is the positive ... wtf !!??

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.H3('PIE'),
            dcc.Graph(id='live-pie', animate=True),
        dcc.Interval(
        id='pie-update',
        interval=1*1000, n_intervals=0
        ),
        ], className="four columns"),
    ], className="row")
])

@app.callback(Output('live-pie', 'figure'), [Input('pie-update', 'n_intervals')])

def update_pie(n):
    pie_positive = line3_coords[n]
    pie_negative = 100 - (line3_coords[n])
    print("\npie_positive: ",pie_positive)
    print("\tpie_negative: ",pie_negative)

    data2 = [{
            'type': 'pie',
            'labels' : ['Positive', 'Negative'],
            'values': [pie_positive, pie_negative],
            'hoverinfo':"none",
            'hole' : '0.45',
            'rotation' : '270',
            'marker': {'colors': ['#96D38C',
                                  '#E1396C']},
            'textinfo':'percent'
            }]


    return {'data': data2,'layout' : go.Layout(legend= {'x': -.4, 'y': 0})}
```

Here is the output from the print statements when it starts to go wrong...

```
pie_positive:  55
    pie_negative:  45

pie_positive:  52
    pie_negative:  48

pie_positive:  50
    pie_negative:  50

pie_positive:  48
    pie_negative:  52

pie_positive:  46
    pie_negative:  54

pie_positive:  44
    pie_negative:  56
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just used a gauge - the pie chart was behaving as it is designed.